# Selenium Firefox Enable Request Blocking

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

is there any way from selenium python to Enable Request Blocking (a functionality available in devtools?

[image]

My goal is to block some requests using wildcarts. I would like to avoid using proxy since firefox already offers this functionality and all the other answer regarding this topic, suggesting to use `profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)` are outdated (since this does not work) and incomplete (since i'm not only trying to block css or images, devtools allow to specify urls with wildcart to block)

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Selenium 4 there will be an API for easier use of ChromeDevTools protocol but I don't see an equivalent of Firefox (https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-4-chrome-dev-tools-samples/). I think that usage of proxy is the only, fully supported solution for you problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep searching for a few days and eventually I will mark your answer as correct